# Dynamic component names in React + Webpack + ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I've defined two React components like this:

```
class CmpA extends React.Component
{ ... }

class CmpB extends React.Component
{ ... }
```

As you can see they are defined in ES6 syntax. And I use Webpack and Babel to trans-compile them to ES5. What I want to do is to store a component definition in a variable and then render it:

```
render() {
    let Cmp = Math.random() > 0.5 ? CmpA : CmpB;
    return <Cmp />;
}
```

But it does not work since the above code translates to:

```
render() {
    var Cmp = Math.random() > 0.5 ? CmpA : CmpB;
    return _react2.default.createElement('Cmp', {});
}
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

**[UPDATE]**

Please also consider that I would need to use `Cmp` like this:

```
render() {
    let Cmp = Math.random() > 0.5 ? CmpA : CmpB;
    return <div><Cmp /></div>;
}
```

Or in other words, I need to be able to name a component dynamically!

**[UPDATE]**

Here's my project's package.json file's content:

```
{
  "name": "expandable-react-redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Mehran",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.2",
    "redux": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the `'Cmp'` when I try it. Are you sure? http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20Cmp%20%3D%20Math.random()%20%3E%200.5%20%3F%20CmpA%20%3A%20CmpB%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CCmp%20%2F%3E%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: The code is pasted here so yeah, I'm pretty sure. Maybe it's because of the dependencies that I've used in my `package.json`! I'll include that in my question.

Comment: It must be something wrong with a bundling process. It may be helpfull to look at your `.babelrc` and `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe You could do it this way:

```
render() {
    const props = { prop1: 10 };
    let Cmp = Math.random() > 0.5 ? <CmpA {...props} /> : <CmpB {...props} />;
    return <div>{Cmp}</div>; 
}
```

Comment: You're answer is correct but not something I'm looking for! I've updated my question to better reflect my problem.

Comment: Updated the answer to match your question.

Comment: Thanks, but can I also somehow set properties for the `{Cmp}`? Like `{Cmp prop1="10"}`?

Comment: You can proxy the props with spread operator: `<CmpA {...props} />`.